# Is it possible to get path from Nextjs app router with id like [id] instead of a custom id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

I am using nextjs App router and [next-intl localize](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/navigation#localized-pathnames) pathname api. I would like to know if its possible to get pathname just like we mention in the navigation file. Currently I get pathname from `NextRequest` with an id like `/de/users/5` but I have it in my navigation file like `/de/users/[id]`.

Maybe this is a completely wrong approach. It will be helpful for me if you guide me how do I solve this?

```
// navigation.ts
import {
 createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation,
 Pathnames
} from 'next-intl/navigation';

export const locales = ['en', 'de'] as const;
export const localePrefix = 'always'; // Default

// The `pathnames` object holds pairs of internal
// and external paths, separated by locale.
const privatePathnames = {
  // Dynamic params are supported via square brackets
  '/users/[id]': {
     en: '/users/[id]',
     de: '/benutzer/[id]'
  },
}
export const pathnames = {
// If all locales use the same pathname, a
// single external path can be provided.
'/': '/',

// If locales use different paths, you can
// specify each external path per locale.
'/about': {
  en: '/about',
  de: '/ueber-uns'
},
...privatePathnames,

} satisfies Pathnames<typeof locales>;

export const {Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter, getPathname} =
   createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation({locales, localePrefix, pathnames});
```

In middleware I am checking if its a private route and user don't have a token then redirect the user to home page

```
// middleware.ts
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import {locales, localePrefix} from './navigation';

const publicRoutes = ["/", "/en", "/de"];
// process "privatePathnames" and returns ["/en/users/[id]", "/de/users/[id]"]
const privateRoutes = privatePathMakerWithLocale(); 
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
   const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
    // A list of all locales that are supported
     locales,
     localePrefix,
     pathnames,
     // Used when no locale matches
     defaultLocale: 'en'
   });
   const res = intlMiddleware(req);
   let isVerifiedUser = false;
   const {pathname, origin} = req.nextUrl;
   const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.value || defaultLocale;
   if (publicRoutes.includes(pathname) && isVerifiedUser) {
      console.log("public route");
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/${locale}/users`);
   }
   // here the pathname is "/de/benutzer/5" while privateRoutes has ["/en/users/[id]", "/de/users/[id]"]
   if (privateRoutes.includes(pathname) && !isVerifiedUser) { 
      console.log("private route");
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/${locale}`);
   }
}
export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(de|en)/:path*']
};
```